# How to hide a drawing in Raylib?

Tags: c++, hide, raylib

I am a beginner at Raylib and I was wondering how to hide an image or sprite in Raylib?

code example:

```
DrawCircle(400,400,100,RED);//circle 1
DrawCircle(200,200,50,RED); //circle 2
//here is where i want a funtion just to delete/hide circle 2
```

Comment: I don't know Raylib. Can't you just not draw it?

Comment: When asking questions it helps us help you immensely if you can show a minimal amount of code that works, so that we can point at parts of it or rewrite parts in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no real way of undrawing something but you could easily control whether you draw it or not in the first place like so:

```cpp
int condition = 1;

DrawCircle(400,400,100,RED);//circle 1

if(condition == 0)
{   
    // Circle is only drawn when condition is true
    DrawCircle(200,200,50,RED); //circle 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the radius to 0 when you want to hide it:

```
float radius{ 50 };   
while(!WindowShouldClose()){
   DrawCircle(400,400,radius,RED);
   if(condition)
       radius = 0; //hide circle
   else{
     radius  = 50;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "draw" an invisible circle for, say,
collision. Then you should implement your own, see https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/blob/master/src/rshapes.c
for the example, look at the functions with "DrawCircle" in it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32286005)